# Can a function of type (unit -> unit) have statically resolved type parameters in F#?

Tags: f#, inline

Why isn't this allowed?

```
type Foo() =
    static member Bar() = ()

let inline bar<^a>() = //ERROR: unexpected infix operator in pattern
    (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> unit)())

//Hypothetical usage: let _ = bar<Foo>()
```

...but this works fine?

```
type Foo() =
    static member Bar() = new Foo()

let inline bar() : ^a =
    (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> ^a)())

let x : Foo = bar()
```

Are functions with statically resolved type parameters required to return an instance of the resolved type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, F# treats the sequence of characters `<^` as an infix operator, so you need to separate them with a space.  As to the question of when you need to explicitly specify constraints, I believe that the rule is that when you explicitly give a function type parameters then you also need to specify any necessary constraints.  Otherwise, if F# can infer the type parameters and constraints, you don't need to specify them.

So this example from your question works fine:

```
let inline bar() :^a =
  (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> ^a)())
```

as would this:

```
let inline bar(x : ^a) =
  (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> unit)())
```

because there's a generic type parameter, but you haven't explicitly placed it on the function, and F# can infer the needed constraint.

On the other hand, if you try to modify your other example to omit the explicit generic parameter:

```
let inline bar() =
  (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> unit)())
```

You'll see that F# won't allow this because there's no way for it to figure out how to instantiate `^a` for any given call of `bar()`.  Thus, you need to provide the type parameter explicitly, and once you do, you also have to explicitly provide the constraint.

Comment: `F# treats the sequence of characters <^ as an infix operator, so you need to separate them with a space` +1

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Spaces inside the angle brackets are needed, along with a constraint.

This works:

```
type Foo() =
    static member Bar() = ()

let inline bar< ^a when ^a : (static member Bar : unit -> unit) >() =
    (^a : (static member Bar : unit -> unit)())

let _ = bar<Foo>()
```

From this we can surmise that the constraint is optional if the function returns an instance of the statically resolved type. Does anyone know if that's the rule?