# How to add LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero / get_Zero to System.String?

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods, type-inference, generic-constraints

Note: I added a lot of `Of interest` comments at the end. These are not mean to suggest that one should use `inline` and `static type parameters` [willy nilly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/willy-nilly), they are there so that one does not have to spend hours searching lots of SO questions related to this question to better understand these concepts.

I know that when one needs to make a function generic and needs a zero (0) value F# provides [GenericZero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370581.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> Resolves to the zero value for any primitive numeric type or any type
>   with a static member called Zero.

So this leads me to believe that to use `GenericZero` with a string type I only have to add a static member called Zero.

Since [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is part of the .Net framework, modifying the .Net source code is not what should be done. However F# provides [Type Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> Type extensions let you add new members to a previously defined object
>   type.

Also F# provides the [String module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx), but that lacks GenericZero.

For a good tutorial on creating type extensions reference: [Attaching functions to types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-extensions/).

The code I tested with:

This is in a project called `Library1`

```
namespace Extension.Test

module Extensions = 

    type System.String with
        static member Something = "a"

        static member StaticProp
            with get() = "b"

        static member Zero
            with get() = "c"
```

This is in a project called `Workspace`

```
namespace Extension.Test
module main =

    open Extensions

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let stringSomething = System.String.Something
        printfn "something: %s" stringSomething

        let staticProperty = System.String.StaticProp
        printfn "staticProperty: %s" staticProperty

        let zeroProperty = System.String.Zero
        printfn "zeroProperty: %s" zeroProperty

        let inline addTest (x : ^a) (y : ^a) : ^a =
            x + y

        let intAdd = addTest 2 LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        let floatAdd = addTest 2.0 LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
//        let stringAdd = addTest "a" LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero

        printfn "intAdd: %A" intAdd
        printfn "floatAdd: %A" floatAdd
//        printfn "stringAdd: %A" stringAdd

        printf "Press any key to exit: "
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        printfn ""

        0 // return an integer exit code
```

when run outputs:

```
something: a
staticProperty: b
zeroProperty: c
intAdd: 2
floatAdd: 2.0
Press any key to exit
```

So I am creating and accessing extension members and using GenericZero without any problems.

The last part is to use GenericZero for a string, however uncommenting the line

```
let stringAdd = addTest "a" LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
```

results in the error:

> The type 'string' does not support the operator 'get_Zero'

I did check the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) but found nothing of help.

Can I add GenericZero to type `System.String`, did I do something wrong in the code, or did I miss something in the documentation?

### TL;DR

### SO questions of interest when searching

[F# - How do I extend a type with get_Zero so I can use an existing type generically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33403433/1243762)
which IMO is a misleading title that should be changed after reading the answers.

[What/where is get_Zero in F#'s int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17251025/1243762)
which has a nice comment from Jack:

> Zero doesn't make sense on string if you think of it in terms of
>   numerics; however, it does make sense to have a Zero member on string
>   which returns the empty string, as that would make string a monoid
>   under string concatenation.

### F# documentation of interest

[Automatic Generalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx)

> The F# compiler, when it performs type inference on a function,
>   determines whether a given parameter can be generic. The compiler
>   examines each parameter and determines whether the function has a
>   dependency on the specific type of that parameter. If it does not, the
>   type is inferred to be generic.

[Type Inference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233180.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The idea of type inference is that you do not have to specify the
>   types of F# constructs except when the compiler cannot conclusively
>   deduce the type.
>
> For those types that you do not specify explicitly, the compiler
>   infers the type based on the context. If the type is not otherwise
>   specified, it is inferred to be generic.

[Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx)

> F# function values, methods, properties, and aggregate types such as
>   classes, records, and discriminated unions can be generic. Generic
>   constructs contain at least one type parameter, which is usually
>   supplied by the user of the generic construct. Generic functions and
>   types enable you to write code that works with a variety of types
>   without repeating the code for each type. Making your code generic can
>   be simple in F#, because often your code is implicitly inferred to be
>   generic by the compiler's type inference and automatic generalization
>   mechanisms.

[Statically Resolved Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx)

> A statically resolved type parameter is a type parameter that is
>   replaced with an actual type at compile time instead of at run time.
>   They are preceded by a caret (^) symbol.
>
> Statically resolved type parameters are **primarily useful in
>   conjunction with member constraints**, which are constraints that allow
>   you to specify that a type argument must have a particular member or
>   members in order to be used. There is no way to create this kind of
>   constraint by using a regular generic type parameter.
>
> In the F# language, there are two distinct kinds of type parameters.
>   The first kind is the standard generic type parameter. These are
>   indicated by an apostrophe ('), as in 'T and 'U. They are equivalent
>   to generic type parameters in other .NET Framework languages. The
>   other kind is statically resolved and is indicated by a caret symbol,
>   as in ^T and ^U.

[Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Inline Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)

> When you use static type parameters, **any functions that are
>   parameterized by type parameters must be inline**.

EDIT

Here is an example that uses `GenericZero` for a user defined type without using an extension that works and two variations showing that `GenericZero` does NOT work for `intrinsic extension` and `optional extension`

Run the program first to see `GenericZero` work then uncomment the lines in `Program.fs` to see the errors for `intrinsic extension` and `optional extension`.

> An **intrinsic extension** is an extension that appears in the same
>   namespace or module, in the same source file, and in the same assembly
>   (DLL or executable file) as the type being extended.
>
> An **optional extension** is an extension that appears outside the
>   original module, namespace, or assembly of the type being extended.
>   Intrinsic extensions appear on the type when the type is examined by
>   reflection, but optional extensions do not. Optional extensions must
>   be in modules, and they are only in scope when the module that
>   contains the extension is open.

In `Library1.fs` in project `Library1`

```
namespace Extension.Test

module module001 = 

    // No extension
    type MyType01(x: string) =
        member this.x = x

        override this.ToString() = this.x.ToString()

        static member Something = MyType01("a")        
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType01, mt2 : MyType01) = MyType01(mt1.x + mt2.x)
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType01, s : string) = MyType01(mt1.x + s)
        static member (+) (s : string, mt2 : MyType01) = MyType01(s + mt2.x)

        static member Zero
            with get() = MyType01("b")

    // uses intrinsic extension
    type MyType02(x: string) =
        member this.x = x

        override this.ToString() = this.x.ToString()

        static member Something = MyType02("g")        
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType02, mt2 : MyType02) = MyType02(mt1.x + mt2.x)
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType02, s : string) = MyType02(mt1.x + s)
        static member (+) (s : string, mt2 : MyType02) = MyType02(s + mt2.x)

//        static member Zero
//            with get() = MyType02("h")

    // uses optional extension
    type MyType03(x: string) =
        member this.x = x

        override this.ToString() = this.x.ToString()

        static member Something = MyType03("m")        
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType03, mt2 : MyType03) = MyType03(mt1.x + mt2.x)
        static member (+) (mt1 : MyType03, s : string) = MyType03(mt1.x + s)
        static member (+) (s : string, mt2 : MyType03) = MyType03(s + mt2.x)

//        static member Zero
//            with get() = MyType03("n")


module module002 = 

    open module001

    // intrinsic extension
    type MyType02 with

        static member Zero
            with get() = MyType02("h")
```

in `Library2.fs` in project `Library2`

```
namespace Extension.Test

open module001

module module003 = 

    type MyType01 with 

        static member Anything = MyType02("c")

    type MyType02 with 

        static member Anything = MyType02("i")

    // optional extension
    type MyType03 with 

        static member Anything = MyType03("p")

        static member Zero
            with get() = MyType03("n")
```

in `Program.fs` in project `Workspace`

```
namespace Workspace

open Extension.Test.module001
open Extension.Test.module002
open Extension.Test.module003

module main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 


        let staticFromBaseType = MyType01.Something
        printfn "MyType01 staticFromBaseType: %A" staticFromBaseType

        let staticFromExtensionType = MyType01.Anything
        printfn "MyType01 staticFromExtensionType: %A" staticFromExtensionType

        let zeroValue = MyType01.Zero
        printfn "MyType01 zeroValue: %A" zeroValue

        let (genericZero: MyType01) = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        printfn "MyType01 genericZero: %A" genericZero

        let staticFromBaseType = MyType02.Something
        printfn "MyType02 staticFromBaseType: %A" staticFromBaseType

        let staticFromExtensionType = MyType02.Anything
        printfn "MyType02 staticFromExtensionType: %A" staticFromExtensionType

        let zeroValue = MyType02.Zero
        printfn "MyType02 zeroValue: %A" zeroValue

//        let (genericZero: MyType02) = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
//        printfn "MyType02 genericZero: %A" genericZero


        let staticFromBaseType = MyType03.Something
        printfn "MyType03 staticFromBaseType: %A" staticFromBaseType

        let staticFromExtensionType = MyType03.Anything
        printfn "MyType03 staticFromExtensionType: %A" staticFromExtensionType

        let zeroValue = MyType03.Zero
        printfn "MyType03 zeroValue: %A" zeroValue

//        let (genericZero: MyType03) = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
//        printfn "MyType03 genericZero: %A" genericZero

        let inline addTest (x : ^a) (y : ^a) : ^a =
            x + y

        let intAdd = addTest 2 LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        let floatAdd = addTest 2.0 LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        let (myType01Add : MyType01) = addTest (MyType01("d")) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
//        let (myType02Add : MyType02) = addTest (MyType02("d")) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
//        let (myType03Add : MyType03) = addTest (MyType03("o")) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero

        printfn "intAdd:      %A" intAdd
        printfn "floatAdd:    %A" floatAdd
        printfn "myType01Add: %A" myType01Add
//        printfn "myType02Add: %A" myType02Add
//        printfn "myType03Add: %A" myType03Add


        printf "Press any key to exit: "
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        printfn ""

        0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Of interest: [Could not extend operators in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8326906/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How to define a type extension for `T[]` in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11849361/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How can I define an extension member on an F# unit of measure?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7154974/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# Extention Methods on Lists, IEnumberable, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579648/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F#: Member constraints to help create seemingly dynamic types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8096021/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Generic zero for generic function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28064695/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Idiomatic way in F# to establish adherence to an interface on type rather than instance level](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978851/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# assuming int when actually dealing with int64](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15008816/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# Generic Math: how to write function with op_GreaterThan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27179275/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F#: Casting to generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19908901/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [What is the difference between the generic signifier ' and the symbol ^ In F# method signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250601/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How to write a function for generic numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4732672/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Statically Resolved Type Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12881828/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Can a function of type (unit -> unit) have statically resolved type parameters in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151079/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How to constrain one type parameter by another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3857528/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [In depth description of statically resolved type parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29081215/1243762)  Read the comments.

Comment: Of interest: [F# cryptic generic constraint error message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28763769/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How this type annotation works, and why the other one does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30305092/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Why are functions bound to the first type they are passed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26667938/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Generically Constraining F# – Part I](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/09/14/constraining-f/) , [Part II](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/09/28/generically-constraining-f-part-ii/), [Part III](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/10/02/generically-constraining-f-part-iii/)

Comment: Of interest: [seq<obj> versus seq<float> in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162249/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F#: Overloading functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2261193/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How to check if a function's type parameters are statically resolved?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16333868/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Type inference failing on generic type with static member constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34437563/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# explicit member constraints: The type variable ^T could not be generalized because it would escape its scope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5904947/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# A type parameter is missing a constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852892/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# missing type constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870935/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [how are abs, sign etc implemented in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193118/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Use of `inline` in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3754862/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [In F#, is it possible to have a tryParse function that infers the target type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33161245/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Generic type constraints and duck typing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13012065/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F#: arithmetic operator and loss of polymorphism (value restriction?)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26633581/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [F# generics / function overloading syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30446386/1243762)

Comment: This was one of the most thoroughly-prepared questions I've ever seen on Stack Overflow, so +1 for that alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension members aren't considered as part of member constraint resolution, so you're out of luck.  With constraints that involve more than one type (such as the constraint on `(+)`), you can work around this via the use of a second type, but for the constraint on `GenericZero` there's no good workaround.

Comment: Ugh! Thanks. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't know that it's explicitly covered by the official documentation.  But see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681142/static-extension-methods-supporting-member-constraints for confirmation (also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346246/why-cant-we-satisfy-f-static-member-constraints-with-type-extensions).  Also, see https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5695277-allow-the-addition-of-operators-in-type-extensions for a related user voice item.

Comment: And see https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/2 for some commentary on why it is nontrivial to add this to the compiler.